# Dynamic Bootstrap table columns: same width for each column (without Java Script)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a table with a dynamic count of columns and I am looking for a solution with html/css/Bootstrap but not with Java Script.

- The table should use 100% of the width (parent container).
- Each column in the table should be displayed with the same width (3 columns = 33%, 4 columns = 25%, ...).
- The result should look like http://jsfiddle.net/La1xbzvm/ but without the hardcoded style `<th style="width: 33%">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the table-layout property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) in order to achieve equally sized columns.

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/powf8vyj/